# FTP Request timeout apenas com Provedor NET

Tags: c#, ftp

Utilizo FTP, para fazer download de arquivos para meu sistema, é um código bem simples, usando FTP REQUEST, porém estou enfrentando problemas com quem utiliza do provedor da NET(e alguns outros porém o da Net é mais evidente)

```
try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario,senha);
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;


            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream rs = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (FileStream ws = new FileStream(local, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                        int bytesRead = rs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        while (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            ws.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            bytesRead = rs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

No request.GetResponse(), o exception retorna, **Tempo Limite da Operação Atingido**, executei o TelNet para testar a porta 21, e a mesma deu certo. Então acredito que tenha algo que eu possa fazer para corrigir esse problema.

Comment: Pode ser o firewall que bloqueou teu programa feito em C# para acessar outros dominios e portas. Não tem como saber. Executou o telnet e o C# na mesma máquina?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento com a mesma maquina utilizando uma internet diferente da certo, então não é o Firewall do Windows, será que talvez o firewall em conjunto com a Rede?

Comment: Não, creio que é firewall da maquina, quando acessa uma rede WIFI ele pode entrar em modo Rede publica e em outro Wifi em Rede particular, o que muda as regras padrões do firewall, mas não tem como afirmar. De qualquer forma o problema não parece ser no código.

Comment: Executei o Telnet, e o C# na mesma maquina e com a mesma internet.

Comment: No win 10 cada rede wifi (SSID) pode estar vinculada a um tipo de rede, particular, empresa ou publica, logo se funcionou em outra rede é pq deveria estar como particular e se não funciona na rede atual é pq deve estar como publica, mas isso não é nem questão da rede e sim nas regras do firewall de cada rede, do qual vc pode "customizar", e provavelmente na primeira vez que vc executou teu C# vc deve ter aplicado alguma permissão de uma janela do windows que apareceu e não notou

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vou tentar verificar esse aspecto.

Comment: Se tiver alguém que tem conhecimento de redes (do Windows mesmo) ai ajuda, é bom vc aprender, mas se não souber nem se arrisque muito a mexer, peça para que alguém o faça, apesar de não ser muito complicado é um local perigoso de se mexer, pode causar um baita problema

Comment: Dê uma lida na documentação, na parte que fala sobre DNS: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.8#coment-rios

Comment: Vou ler @BrunoWarmling, vou tentar também alterar o TimeOut para ver se tem alguma diferença no retorno do erro.

Comment: Segundo o que diz ali, o `Timeout` é infinito, então poderia ser problema ao tentar resolver o DNS... Tenta usar o IP direto pra ver se ocorre o mesmo problema.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling vou testar mudar para o ip, também.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling matou a charada, o problema está sendo em tentar resolver o DNS, vou fazer mais alguns testes e posto a solução.

Answer (score 0):

O problema, estava na resolução de dns o ISP, não estava conseguindo resolver o DNS do endereço do Servidor, fazendo o teste diretamente com o IP, o mesmo passa a funcionar. Porém como se trata de uma hospedagem com IP Dinamico, é necessario recuperar o IP do momento do Acesso.

```
  IPHostEntry hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry("servidor.com.br");
  IPAddress[] ip = hostname.AddressList;
```

Fazendo dessa maneira é retornado o IP, e utilizo ele ao invés do NOME, fazendo com que a função funcione normalmente em ambos os casos.